# WAMP installed, Apache running, but not MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am trying to install WAMP, webpages to be stored in localhost.

I have the relevant packages downloaded. Inside WAMP  Apache running fine, but not mySQL. WAMP Icon is orange.

I have not downloaded anything regarding MySQL, before downloading WAMP.

What should i do?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some of the commands you've used to try to reach your goal?

Comment: just curious. What operating system? What WAMP version? Why the VC++ stuff? Where did you find the information to install that stuff before installing WAMP (a web link would help or a link to some documentation)? I am curious as normally the 'WAMP' package is complete and you don't need to install anything special unless it is mentioned  after you install the package.

Comment: Look at the MYSQL Error Log `left click wampmanager->MYSQL->Error Log` what is shown in there. If nothing interesting there also check the Windows Event Viewer for messages from MYSQL

Comment: ALso are you sure you dont have another MYSQL Server installed on your system?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like MySQL is not initiated. I recommend, go to config->tick all modules, close. Restart computer, start WAMP Server. Disable firewall. If still no use, install a fresh copy.